# ISO checksum menu in nautilus

Tags: nautilus-actions

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 x64, Unity, and Nautilus 3.2.1
I want to be able to perform checksum ISO in Nautilus.

I have searched and found:

http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/nautilus-actions-extra-add-more-features-to-ubuntu-context-menu/

and perform the procedures written in it.
Once completed, the other menus appear, except the menu for "checksum verification".

[image]

Then, when I run

```
gksu nautilus-actions-config-tool
```

I just asked to enter a user password, and .... nothing happens.
What should I do, to bring up the "checksum verification" menu?

I am very grateful for any response or advice given.

Comment: here is the alternative method http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/install-nautilus-actions-3-1-5-with-alternative-method-to-avoid-error/

Comment: @tachyons, I've finished downloading, and proceed to install, and there are errors in the install. But I do not know how and where to post on this forum, the output of the procedure that has been done.

Comment: checking for GTK3... no
configure: error: unable to build against Gtk+-3.0 library

Answer (score 1):

After a while, I finally tried this way:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-menu-checksum
```

and now the menu is available for writing checksum.
Thank you for your response.